# Downloading all PDFs from URL

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a website that has several hundred PDFs. I need to iterate through, and download every PDF to my local machine. I would like to use [rvest](/questions/tagged/rvest). Attempt:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://example.com"

scrape <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node(".ms-vb2 a") %>%
  download.file(., 'my-local-directory')
```

How do I grab each PDF from the link? The `download.file()` does not work, and I have no clue how to get each file. I just get this error:

> Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url,
>   as_html = as_html,  :    xmlParseEntityRef: no name [68]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://example.com"
page<- html_session(url,config(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE))

links<-page %>% html_nodes(".ms-vb2 a") %>% html_attr("href")
subject<-page %>% html_nodes(".ms-vb2:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
name<-links<-page %>% html_nodes(".ms-vb2 a") %>% html_text()

for(i in 1:length(links)){
  pdf_page<-html_session(URLencode(paste0("https://example.com",links[i])),config(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE))
  writeBin(paste0(name[i],"-",subject[i],".pdf")
}
```

The URL is http so had to use the `config(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE)`

`writeBin` name the file according to your necessity. I have just named it `ok_1.pdf` `ok_2.pdf` and so on

Comment: If I wanted to name the files what they're named on the website, can I replace the `"ok_%d.pdf"` with something like `[links].pdf`?

Comment: Like for example, on the site there's a "Subject" line. Can I change the name of the saved file to the "Name" and "Subject" combined? Throw another `paste0` in there? Or is that a substantial lift?

Comment: I have edited the code now as per your needs. @papelr